# Apart from GET and POST what forms can I use to send form data?

Tags: html, forms, post, get, alternate

This is only a thought as I think there was one on a website I visited before. It allowed to use the input file type which when I try to do with post fails.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The sending of data can only be done using POST. GET must be strictly be used to get data for listing. You are confused about using Restful services. As, far as I know data can be sent to the server in the following 2 ways:

1. POST service by HTML form redirecting to a php page
2. Making Ajax hit by JavaScript, jQuery, AngualarJs, etc making use of xmlhttp request.

Though there may be other means to send data to server, these are mostly used for sending form data.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to send data in a GET request. Telling a search engine what term you want to search for is a classic example. Don't confuse "sending data" with not being [safe or idempotent](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms can only be used to make POST and GET requests. No other values for [the method attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method) are supported.

Using JavaScript, you can use just about [any HTTP method](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) you like, but that doesn't directly involve a form.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("DELETE", "/example/thing/to/delete");
xhr.send();
```